# cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby error?

Tags: ruby, snmp

I tried to import my Vendor's MIBs using import.rb,

i have put my .mib file(s) into a directory called mib .

/snmp-1.2.0# ls ./mib/

> cpq54nn.mib    cpqdmii.mib   cpqhost.mib      cpql2mgt.mib   cpqrack.mib      cpqservice.mib  cpqstsys.mib
>     .......

OS has the libsmi package installed:

`libsmi2-dev install`

`libsmi2ldbl:amd64 install`

I got the err msg as below ,

```
snmp-1.2.0$ ruby -d import.rb mibs/
```

> Exception LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:1203 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
>   ExceptionNameError' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/class_loader.rb:67 - uninitialized constant BigDecimal
>   Exception NameError' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/class_loader.rb:67 - uninitialized constant DateTime
>   ExceptionNameError' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/core_ext.rb:16 - methodto_yaml' not defined in Object
>   ExceptionNameError' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/core_ext.rb:29 - methodyaml_as' not defined in Module
>   ExceptionNameError' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/deprecated.rb:81 - undefined methodto_yaml_properties' for classObject'
>   I truly appreciate ... your help in resolving the problem.

Comment: What does "mib" mean in this context?

Comment: mib directory is my Vendor's MIBs file

Comment: That's a circular definition. What module are you trying to use here? This is not just plain Ruby.

Comment: Are you mean import.rb ? it's for MIB  OID translation . get from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hallidave/ruby-snmp/master/import.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're loading in a YAML file that has frozen classes that aren't defined you'll have to load those prior to deserializing this file.

I don't know what you'll encounter, it just runs until it stumbles over the first thing, but if you need `DateTime` then `require 'date'` might fix that. Whatever class is missing you need to do the same thing, track down where it's defined and `require` it prior to the `YAML.load` part.